# Failed to fill utterance template - Rasa Chatbot

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

First I ran the command `rasa run actions` and then I ran `rasa train` and then `rasa x`. I get an error.

Failed to fill utterance template 'Play the game [ ] {mario_link}'. Tried to replace 'mario_link' but could not find a value for it. There is no slot with this name nor did you pass the value explicitly when calling the template. Return template without filling the template.

domain.yml file

```
session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
intents:
- mario
responses:
  utter_game_mario:
  - text: Play the game [ ] {mario_link}
actions:
- action_mario
```

actions.py file

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher


class ActionHelloWorld(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_mario"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
            # dispatcher.utter_message(text="Hello World!")

            link = "https://supermarioemulator.com/supermario.php"

            dispatcher.utter_template("utter_game_mario", tracker, link=link)
            return []
```

nlu.md file

```
## intent:mario
- i want to play mario
- start mario
- play mario
```

endpoints.yml file

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

stories.md file

```
## game
* mario
    - action_mario
```

I have used these references and did not work for me:

Re-installed latest version of Rasa: https://forum.rasa.com/t/getting-an-error-while-using-custom-output-payload/11802

No idea what the solution is here: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/4550

This did not make any sense: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/pull/4079/files/6c14ab262e915369915876425670843ab348201e

Please help. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes and it should work

**in domain.yml:**

```
- text: Play the game {mario_link}
```

**in actions.py**

add this line

```
tracker.get_slot('mario_link')
```

and change this one

```
dispatcher.utter_template("utter_game_mario", tracker, mario_link=link)
```

But what I would personally do is not using an utter_response at all in here and just use the action and print the answer using **dispatcher.utter_message()**

Answer (score 0):

Utter responses are not supposed to be dynamic. Use the action by itself to create a dynamic response.

Comment: Am I not using action as a response in my stories.md file?

Comment: Yes it is. What I'm suggesting is to use it by itself without an utter response